# A question about lattices and their being partially-ordered sets, rather than total-ordered sets

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Am I correct in saying that, given *a* and *b* are elements of **S**, the *join(a, b)* and *meet(a, b)* won't be either *a* or *b*, if there is no order between a and b?

Comment: In fact, $a\land b = a$ if and only if $a\leq b$; $a\lor b = a$ if and only if $a\geq b$. So if $a$ and $b$ are not comparable in the lattice, then you are correct, $a\land b\notin\{a,b\}$ and $a\lor b\notin\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(So the question doesn't remain without answers).

Yes, you are correct. If $a$ and $b$ are comparable, say $a\leq b$, then $a\land b = a$ and $a\lor b= b$; conversely, since $a\land b\leq a$ and $a\land b\leq b$ for all $a$ and $b$, if $a\land b\in\{a,b\}$, then $a$ and $b$ are comparable (similar if $a\lor b\in{a,b}$).

Comment: thanks! I was just waiting for you to make an answer so I could checkmark it hehe.